# How many rows in dataframe contain question mark symbol

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have dataframe made from csv in which missing data is represented by ? symbol. I want to check how many rows there are in which ? occurs with number of occurrence.
So far i made this but it shows number of all rows,  not only that ones in which ? occurs.

```
print(sum([True for idx,row in df.iterrows() if 
any(row.str.contains('[?]'))]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` + `str.contains`, assuming all your columns are strings.

```
c = np.sum(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\?')).values)
```

If you need to select string columns only, use `select_dtypes` -

```
i = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['number']).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\?')) 
c = np.sum(i.values)
```

Alternatively, to find the *number* of rows containing `?` in them, use

```
c = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\?')).any(axis=1).sum()
```

---

Demo -

```
df

      A      B
0   aaa   ?xyz
1   bbb  que!?
2     ?    ddd
3  foo?    fff
```

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\?')).any(1).sum()
4
```

Comment: But this will show number of all question marks not the number of rows with question marks. If there will be row with two question marks it will add 2 not 1

Comment: @kurbielp You described your problem as such. For your revised problem, use `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\?')).any(1).sum()`